# Can't Generate Sitemaps for sites including Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitemap

I am trying to generate a sitemap for two of my sites but both online and local software doesn't work. The site www.xsitemap.com says that the root URL is a bad URL. All others, including my software WebCEO simply run and produce nothing.

I have several other sites for which the sitemap generators work well.  These are the only two sites I have that include JavaScript and jQuery - hence the tags.

It's probably a stupid error by me but I'm really baffled and could certainly use some help.

It's worth saying that I've just had WebCEO produce an error saying that there is a script error (a missing ')' on line 2459).  There are 439 lines of code so it occurs in one of the includes but more likely that I've got an extra opening '(' in my code.  The sites work ok though.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand I did not encounter any problems using A1 Sitemap Generator (You can add support for searching for links in Javascript in "Scan website | Crawler options" if you disable "easy mode")

The only thing I can think of causing problems (not that I encountered them) would be if you used AJAX somehow. (At least if you did not also then implement Google's http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ proposed solution to that.)

Comment: Hi Tom.  Thanks for your reply.  I found the problem eventually and it was nothing to do with javascript or jquery.  There was a vbscript error at the very bottom of a very long page.  It was written in white text on a white background so I didn't see it - I spotted it though!